# Como definir um intervalo de tempo mínimo entre inserções no banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Eu tenho um formulário de submissão, onde adiciona comentários ao banco de dados e os mostra na página.

O problema é que eu quero defenir o formulário para que as pessoas só consigam fazer submissões a cada 10 minutos. Isto é, um usuário só poderá publicar um segundo comentário 10 minutos após ter publicado o primeiro.

Como poderei fazer isso?

A minha submissão começa assim:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitPost'])) {

    //mysqli_real_escape_string($db, )

    $postcomment = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['message']);
    $uploaded = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['upload']);
    $titleID = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['title']);

     ...
}
```

A estrutura da tabela `comentarios`:

```
 | id_steam (users) | title | comment | date |
```

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao [pt.so]. Aconselho primeiramente você fazer o [tour] pelo sistema para entender de forma clara como tudo funciona e, assim, evitar quaisquer possíveis transtornos futuros. Quanto à pergunta, tem como detalhar melhor? Você quer que o formulário fique disponível na página a cada 10 minutos para todos os usuários? Se sim, por quanto tempo ele ficará disponível? Ou deseja que cada usuário possa submeter um comentário a cada 10 minutos (se eu comento agora, só poderei comentar novamente após 10 minutos)?

Comment: Sim exatamente, cada user so podera comentar a cada 10min após o comentario feito.

Comment: Se for o mesmo usuário da pergunta, não utilize a área de respostas para comentários adicionais. Logo abaixo da pergunta existe a área de comentários que tem este fim.

Comment: Uma ideia de solução é: antes de você inserir o novo comentário no banco de dados, verificar o valor da data/hora do último comentário feito pelo usuário. Se houver uma diferença deste valor para o valor atual de mais de 10 minutos, você prossegue com a inserção, mas caso contrário, você exibe uma mensagem de alerta. Para isso, seria necessário sabermos qual é a estrutura da tabela de comentários e como você identifica cada usuário.

Comment: Peço desculpa por estar a criar respostas assim, mas é que não consigo registar de momento, mais logo registo. Pedia-lhe que ajuda-se desta forma por enquanto... bem... Tabela Comentairos: | id_steam (users) | title | comment | date | Como irei realizar essa verificação?